# How can I call passed in args function with passed in args arguments in Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have three arguments in my function. Third argument is function which I want to call with argument from second argument. I there any way to make it?

```
callFuncWithArgs(
  nthArg(1),
  nthArg(2),
)(null, 3, a => a * a) // 9
```

Comment: Yes there is a way you can make it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox How?

Comment: Depends on what you’ve tried so far

Comment: I don't really follow your example, which seems to contain some extraneous complications - but you can easily define a function in which one argument is called with another as its argument, just `const f = (func, val) => func(val)` will do that.

Comment: Are you looking for something as simple as `const foo = (_, x, f) => f(x)`? Or do you really need the API above, where the initial arguments to `callFuncWithArgs` takes functions that say how to *extract* the two relevant arguments from the full arguments list and then pass the actual arguments to the resulting function?  That's slightly more complex, but certainly not too hard: `const callFuncWithArgs = (getX, getFn) => (...args) => getFn (...args) (getX (...args))`

Answer (score 0):

```
converge(applyTo, [nthArg(1), nthArg(2)])
```